# Config::get() not working laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to access array from config file and use it in my dropdown list.

```
<select id="iconSelector" name="iconChoose" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach(array(Config::get('azima')) as $icon)
        <option value="{{$icon}}">{{$icon}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I have 'azima.php' file in config folder, which returns array and looks like this

```
<?php

return [
    "ti-arrow-up",
    "ti-arrow-right",
    "ti-arrow-left",
    "ti-angle-double-up"
    ];
```

The problem is it is working fine in other projects. What could be the problem?

Comment: what's the laravel version you're using?

Comment: @MochamadGufronEfendi 5.4.28

Comment: I think you should get config values in a controller and pass them in your view.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola still the same... not working

Comment: Did you tried config helper function like this: `config('azima');`. and yeah remove array casting as @Andre Madarang suggested.

Comment: Did you tried to `var_dump(Config::get('azima'));`?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola yes.. It is passing Null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148851/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-azima).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get `null` maybe because the file hasn't been autoloaded. Clearing the cache and autoload dumping should do the trick

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast it to an array:

```
<select id="iconSelector" name="iconChoose" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach(Config::get('azima') as $icon)
        <option value="{{$icon}}">{{$icon}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: yeah I did without array() initially.. it threw an error that argument for @foreach has to be an array.. I don't know where it went wrong.. It worked fine for other project.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on terminal

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: How does this answer address the question?